# Getting an unsafe fixed pointer to the start of a rectangular array

Tags: c#, .net, unsafe, fixed-statement, multidimensional-array

Consider a 2D, rectangular array. Say:

```
int[,] values = new int[len1, len2];
```

How can you iterate through all of its values in `unsafe` code?

Answer (score 2):

The following works in an `unsafe` context.

```
fixed (int* baseOffset = values)
{
    var offset = baseOffset;
    var count = len1 * len2;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int value = *offset;
        // Do whatever you need to do here
        offset++;
    }
}
```

Note that to get a pointer to the first item in an array, the types must match. So if you have a `byte*` which you want to treat as `ushort*`, you cannot cast the pointer within the `fixed` statement's parentheses, although you can do this within the block.